# RestClient can not get response

Tags: php, rest-client

i'm newbie in PHP. I use restclient (https://github.com/tcdent/php-restclient) to request as below:

```
<?php

require 'restclient.php';

        $api = new RestClient();
        $result = $api->get("https://api.github.com/repos/phatls/CallCenter_Customer/issues?state=all");
        if($result->info->http_code == 200)
            echo ($result->response);
        else 
            echo "false";

?>
```

It works greatly. But with:

```
<?php

        require 'restclient.php';
        $api = new RestClient();
        $result = $api->get("http://beka.vn/api/BkMobileLogin/GetGroup/phat.ls");
        if($result->info->http_code == 200)
             echo ($result->response);
         else 
            echo "false";

?>
```

It returns false. Please help me if you don't have any inconvenient.
thanks

Comment: Api url itself is not working http://beka.vn/api/BkMobileLogin/GetGroup/phat.ls. So, your code will work with working url (correct url)

Comment: @Maya Shah
http://beka.vn/api/BkMobileLogin/GetGroup/phat.ls
You can check by paste it to your browser, it works okie.

Comment: Yep, I checked [http://beka.vn/api/BkMobileLogin/GetGroup/phat.ls](http://beka.vn/api/BkMobileLogin/GetGroup/phat.ls) is not accessible. Should be this problem

Comment: @aahung thank you for your comment. In VietNam, it is okie. If so, I have to check again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please read official page documentation.[link](https://github.com/tcdent/php-restclient)

Or follow this official example

```
$api = new RestClient([
'base_url' => "http://vimeo.com/api/v2", 
'format' => "php"
]);
$result = $api->get("tcdent/info");
if($result->info->http_code == 200)
         echo ($result->response);
     else 
        echo "false";
```

Comment: http://gmin.epizy.com/cart/login.php. It also return false. Please help me check it.

Comment: try to pass another url